# event sales_order_invoice_save_after always fired twice

Tags: magento, events

I did an observer for the event "sales_order_invoice_save_after" to export the invoice and order data each time the admin creates an invoice to a DB on SQL Server. The connection is successful. But it doesn't matter what I try the event is always fired twice. I have the data saved two times on the DB.  I tried with everything:

1.- I’ve created a flag in the observer using the registry and it doesn’t work.

```
public function exportInvoice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){

    try{


    if(Mage::registry('sql_salvado')){
        return $this;
    }


//My code


Mage::register('sql_salvado',true,true); 

    }catch(Mage_Core_Exception $e){
         Mage::log("No fue posible exportar pedidos a SQL Server " . $e->getMessage());
    }

    return $this;
```

2.- I’ve also created a method in the class that verify the SQL Server DB to check if the Invoice is already register and if not it continues with the registration or stop it, but  it doesn’t work. Magento simply fires the event two times.

```
if($this->_verifyInsertion($order['invoice']) == true){
        Mage::log('Invoice ya existe no se va a repetir', null, 'escritura_sql.log');
        return $this;
    }else{
```

This is the example of the method:

```
protected function _verifyInsertion($invoice){

    $_servidor = $this->_mssqlhost.':'.$this->_mssqlpuerto.$this->_mssqlinstancia;
    $link = mssql_connect( $_servidor,$this->_mssqlusr,$this->_mssqlpsswd );

    if (!$link || !mssql_select_db($this->_mssqlbd, $link)) {
        die('No me pude conectar o seleccionar la BD!');
    }

    $query = mssql_query("SELECT id_order, invoice FROM [order] WHERE invoice LIKE '$invoice'");
    $fila = mssql_fetch_object($query);
    if($fila->invoice == $invoice){

        Mage::log("$invoice ya existe no debes repetirte", null, 'escritura_sql.log');
        return true;
    }else{
        Mage::log("$invoice no existe, escribelo...", null, 'escritura_sql.log');
        return false;
    }
```

3.- I’ve also try with “sales_order_invoice_save_before” and “sales_order_invoice_register” without success. Nothing is working, Magento still firing the event two times.

I want to know if there's a way to know if the event was already fired and then stop it the second time. Could somebody point me in the right direction?.

---

Christopher, first of all thanks for your kind help.

Here is the config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Cmm_Qad>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Cmm_Qad>
</modules>

<global>
    <models>
        <qad>
            <class>Cmm_Qad_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>qad_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </qad>
        <qad_mysql4>
            <class>Cmm_Qad_Model_Mysql4</class>
        </qad_mysql4>
    </models>
    <events>
        <sales_order_invoice_save_after>
            <observers>
                <cmm_qad_pedidos_exporta>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Cmm_Qad_Model_Pedidos_Exporta</class>
                    <method>exportInvoice</method>
                </cmm_qad_pedidos_exporta>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_invoice_save_after>
    </events>
    <blocks>
        <qad>
            <class>Cmm_Qad_Block</class>
        </qad>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <qad>
            <class>Cmm_Qad_Helper</class>
        </qad>  
    </helpers>
</global>

<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <cmm_qad_stock>
            <run>
                <schedule><cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <model>cmm/qad::sincronizaInventario</model>
            </run>
        </cmm_qad_stock>
        <cmm_qad_precios>
            <run>
                <schedule><cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <model>cmm/qad::sincronizaPrecios</model>
            </run>
        </cmm_qad_precios>
    </jobs>
</crontab>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <qad>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Cmm_Qad</module>
                <frontName>qad</frontName>
            </args>
        </qad>
    </routers>
</admin>

<adminhtml>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <mage_adminhtml>
                <files>
                    <qad>Cmm_Qad.csv</qad>
                </files>
            </mage_adminhtml>
        </modules>
    </translate>

    <menu>
        <catalog>
            <children>
                <qad_adminform translate="title" module="qad">
                    <title>Sincronizar con QAD</title>
                    <action>qad/adminhtml_qad</action>
                </qad_adminform>
            </children>
        </catalog>
    </menu>

    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <catalog>
                        <children>
                            <qad_adminform>
                                <title>QAD ERP</title>
                            </qad_adminform>
                        </children>
                    </catalog>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <!-- Segunda inserción por configuracion-->
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <qad>
                                        <title>QAD - All</title>
                                    </qad>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <!-- /Segunda inserción por configuración -->

    <layout>
        <updates>
            <qad>
                <file>qad.xml</file>
            </qad>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

And here is the code above the insertion:

```
require_once(Mage::getBaseDir('lib').  '/cmm/mssql.php');


/**
 * Clase de escritura de Datos a SQL Server para CMM
 */
class Cmm_Qad_Model_Pedidos_Exporta{

private static $_conexion;
private static $_dateCreated;
private static $_dateUpdated;
private static $_mssqlhost;   
private static $_mssqlpuerto;     
private static $_mssqlinstancia; 
private static $_mssqlusr;
private static $_mssqlpsswd;
private static $_mssqlbd;

//Variables para valores identitys
private static $_id_client;
private static $_id_address;
private static $_id_order;
private static $_id_detail;


/*
 * We open the connection to SQL Server in the constructor
 *
*/  
public function __construct(){ 

    ini_set("display_errors",1);

    $this->_mssqlhost                 = Mage::getStoreConfig('qad/qad_group/mssql_host', Mage::app()->getStore());
    $this->_mssqlpuerto               = Mage::getStoreConfig('qad/qad_group/mssql_puerto', Mage::app()->getStore());
    $this->_mssqlinstancia            = Mage::getStoreConfig('qad/qad_group/mssql_instancia', Mage::app()->getStore());
    $this->_mssqlusr                  = Mage::getStoreConfig('qad/qad_group/mssql_usr', Mage::app()->getStore());
    $this->_mssqlpsswd                = Mage::getStoreConfig('qad/qad_group/mssql_pass', Mage::app()->getStore());
    $this->_mssqlbd                   = Mage::getStoreConfig('qad/qad_group/mssql_bd', Mage::app()->getStore());
    $this->_dateCreated               = Varien_Date::now();
    $this->_dateUpdated               = Varien_Date::now();

    /*
     * Open the connection with SQL Server
     * */
    $_servidor                        = $this->_mssqlhost.':'.$this->_mssqlpuerto.$this->_mssqlinstancia;
    $this->_conexion                  = new mssqlClass();
    $this->_conexion->connect($_servidor,$this->_mssqlusr,$this->_mssqlpsswd);
    $this->_conexion->select($this->_mssqlbd);


}

/**
* Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_after', $this->_getEventData());
* protected $_eventPrefix = 'sales_order';
* protected $_eventObject = 'order';
* event: sales_order_save_after
*/
public function exportInvoice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){

    if(Mage::registry('sql_salvado') == 1){

        Mage::unregister('sql_salvado');
        return NULL;
    }

    $invoice                          = $observer->getInvoice();
    $pedido                           = $invoice->getOrder();
    $client                           = array();
    $client_del_address               = array();
    $order                            = array();
    $order_detail                     = array();

    /*
     * Recopilamos los datos
    */

    //Client
    $client['name']                   = $pedido->getCustomerFirstname()." ".$pedido->getCustomerLastname();
    $client['type']                   = 1;
    $client['rfc']                    = "UWXU8609121O6";
    $client['curp']                   = "CMM";
    $client['email']                  = $pedido->getCustomerEmail();
    $client['phone']                  = $pedido->getCustomerTelephone();
    $client['phone2']                 = $pedido->getCustomerTelephone();
    $client['clave_qad']              = "CLAVEQ";
    $client['address']                = $pedido->getBillingAddress()->getStreet(); //Es otro array
    $client['zipcode']                = $pedido->getBillingAddress()->getPostcode();
    $client['colony']                 = "Colonia";
    $client['country']                = $pedido->getBillingAddress()->getCountry();
    $client['id_state']               = 1;
    $client['id_country']             = 2;


    //Client_del_address
    $client_del_address['address']    = $pedido->getShippingAddress()->getStreet(); //Es un array()
    $client_del_address['zipcode']    = $pedido->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
    $client_del_address['colony']     = "Colonia";
    $client_del_address['country']    = $pedido->getShippingAddress()->getCountry();
    $client_del_address['is_state']   = 1;
    $client_del_address['id_country'] = 2;


    //Order
    $order['invoice']                 = (int) $invoice->getIncrementId();
    $order['status']                  = 1;
    $order['subtotal_notax']          = $invoice->getSubtotal();
    $order['subtotal_tax']            = $invoice->getSubtotal() + $invoice->getTaxAmount();
    $order['total_tax']               = $invoice->getTaxAmount();
    $order['total']                   = $invoice->getGrandTotal();


    //Se abre la validación del semáforo
    if($this->_verifyInsertion($order['invoice']) == true){
        Mage::log('Invoice ya existe no se va a repetir', null, 'escritura_sql.log');
        return NULL;
    }else{
        Mage::log('Invoice es nuevo', null, 'escritura_sql.log');

    //Validamos que el cliente exista o no exista. 
    if($this->_existeCliente($client['email']) == true){
        Mage::log('El cliente existe', null, 'escritura_sql.log');
        if($this->_insertaDirEnvio($client_del_address, $client) == true){
//The rest of the code...
```

And what I see in the log is that the process is only running one time, in fact my validation works but the registry is always written twice. Here is an example of one of the methods that makes an insertion on the DB

```
/*
 * Inserta clientes 
*/

protected function _insertaCliente(array $client){
    $sql_client="INSERT INTO [client] (name, type, rfc, curp, email, phone1, phone2, clave_qad, address, zipcode, colony, county, id_state, id_country, date_created, date_updated) VALUES ('".$client['name']."', '".$client['type']."', '".$client['rfc']."', '".$client['curp']."', '".$client['email']."', '".$client['phone1']."', '".$client['phone2']."', '".$client['clave_qad']."', '".$client['address'][0]."', '".$client['zipcode']."', '".$client['colony']."', '".$client['country']."', '".$client['id_state']."', '".$client['id_country']."', '".$this->_dateCreated."', '".$this->_dateUpdated."') SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID=@@IDENTITY";

    if($this->_conexion->query($sql_client)){
        $_identity = mssql_fetch_assoc($this->_conexion->query($sql_client));
        $this->_id_client = $_identity['LAST_INSERT_ID'];
        return true;
    }else{
        echo $this->_conexion->getLastErrorMessage()." Inserta Cliente";
        return false;
    }


}
```

In all my insertions I'm making another select "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID=@@IDENTITY" because SQL server has identity fields to auto increment its id's. Then I save that identitys in other vars (that I created in the constructor) and reuse it for later insertions, such invoices or order_details, etc.

THANKS IN ADVANCE FOR ANY KIND OF HELP!!

Answer (score 0):

I checked the signature of Mage::register (because i did not know the third parameter):

```
public static function register($key, $value, $graceful = false)
```

When $graceful is set to true, the method throws no exception at all.

So try this (untested):

```
public function exportInvoice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){

  if(Mage::registry('sql_salvado')){
    return $this;
  }

  // your code here

  try{
    Mage::register('sql_salvado',true); 
  } catch(Mage_Core_Exception $e){
    Mage::log("No fue posible exportar pedidos a SQL Server " . $e->getMessage());
  }

  return $this;
}
```

then verify if this piece of code gets executed, i.e. if the module's config.xml is correct.

Comment: Christopher, thanks for y our help.  I try with your solution but it doesn't work. The event is still firing twice. At this point I don't know what else to do =( . I can't understand why in my own log I see the execution just one time but in the DB I see the record registered twice.

Comment: It's important to clarify that I have a public function __construct(){} method in my observer??

Comment: Ok that already clears things up. If i understand you correctly exportInvoice gets executed only once (according Mage::log()) but you still have two records in the db? Maybe show your config.xml and the rest of the observer (above all the sqlserver insertion code).